# Print and delete chr(0) entries in a list of strings

Tags: r, data-science

I have a vector of strings in R, some of its indices are chr(0). I want to print those indices which are chr(0) and then remove them. I am unable to do any of the two tasks. What I tried for first scenario are 3 different solutions:

```
(1) temp <- keepColumns[keepColumns == character(0)]
(2) temp2 <- which(keepColumns[]== "0")
(3) temp2 <- foreach(i=1:length(keepColumns)) %do% if (length(keepColumns[i]) == 0) print("Empty")
#if (identical(keepColumns[i],character(0))) { print(i) }
```

In all cases, value of temp turns out to be

```
> temp2
integer(0)
```

To remove chr(0), I have tried similar solutions:

```
keepColumnsList = keepColumns[!identical(keepColumns, character(0))]
```

but keepColumnsList is the same as the original vector.

The list is as follows:

```
> keepColumns
[[1]]

> keepColumns
[[1]]
[1] "P2.11FIC2026_PV"

[[2]]
[1] "P2.11FIC2046D_PV"

[[3]]
[1] "P2.11FI2046"

[[4]]
[1] "P2.11FY2048I"

[[5]]
[1] "P2.11FIC2030_PV"

[[6]]
[1] "P2.11FIC2011A_PV"

[[7]]
[1] "P2.11FIC2017_OP"

[[8]]
[1] "P2.11HIC5001"

[[9]]
[1] "P2.11HIC5002"

[[10]]
[1] "P2.11HIC5003"

[[11]]
[1] "P2.11PI5014"

[[12]]
[1] "P2.11TIC5003_PV"

[[13]]
[1] "P2.11TIC5011_PV"

[[14]]
[1] "P2.11FIC5011_PV"

[[15]]
character(0)

[[16]]
[1] "P2.11TI5001"

[[17]]
[1] "P2.11PIC2031_PV"

[[18]]
[1] "P2.11PIC2045_PV"

[[19]]
[1] "P2.11HIC2026E"

[[20]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001A1"

[[21]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001A7"

[[22]]
[1] "P2.11FI2029"

[[23]]
[1] "P2.11AI2026"

[[24]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001A8"

[[25]]
[1] "P2.11TI2076"

[[26]]
[1] "P2.11TI2068"

[[27]]
[1] "P2.11TI2027"

[[28]]
[1] "P2.11TI2071"

[[29]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G6"

[[30]]
[1] "P2.11TI2047"

[[31]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G1"

[[32]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G2"

[[33]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G3"

[[34]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G4"

[[35]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001G5"

[[36]]
[1] "P2.11AI2001H5"

[[37]]
[1] "P2.11FI5001"

[[38]]
[1] "P2.11FI5021"

[[39]]
[1] "P2.11FI5023"

[[40]]
[1] "P2.11PI5004"

[[41]]
[1] "P2.11TI5009"

[[42]]
[1] "P2.11TI5010"

[[43]]
[1] "P2.11TI5026"

[[44]]
[1] "P2.11TI5034"

[[45]]
[1] "P2.11TI5036"

[[46]]
[1] "P2.11TI5038"

[[47]]
[1] "P2.11TI5045"

[[48]]
[1] "P2.11FI2001A"

[[49]]
[1] "P2.11FI2001B"

[[50]]
character(0)

[[51]]
character(0)

[[52]]
[1] "P2.11TI2061"

[[53]]
[1] "P2.11TI2062"

[[54]]
[1] "P2.11TI2063"

[[55]]
[1] "P2.11TI2064"

[[56]]
[1] "P2.11TI2065"

[[57]]
[1] "P2.11TI2066"
```

Comment: it looks like `keepColumns` is a list, is that true? `class(keepColumns)`?

Comment: You have a list. Try: `Filter(length, keepColumns)` to get the element not equal to `character(0)` and if you want to print those that are equal to `character(0)` then you can do `Filter(function(x) length(x)==0, keepColumns)`.

Comment: yes it is a "list"

Comment: use this `keepColumns[sapply(keepColumns, length) != 0]` to drop and index locations with == 0

Comment: temp2 <- Filter(function(x) length(x)==0, keepColumns) gives a vector of 3 values of chr(0), but not their indices

Comment: @YasirKhan what exactly do you need the indices for? You are trying to remove elements and `Filter` does just that for you.

Comment: I want to indicate whether there is an error in the input data. I read data from a CSV file and check whether the necessary columns are present

Comment: this works: Filter(function(x) length(x)==0, keepColumns)

Answer (score 0):

This works in removing the entries with chr(0) value:

```
Filter(function(x) length(x)==0, keepColumns)
```

To display of the indices of the list where `chr(0)` values are, the following should work:

```
Filter(function(x) length(keepColumns[[x]])==0, seq_along(keepColumns))
```

<strike>But still no solution for displaying index number of all chr(0) entries in a vector</strike>.